# What is the best way to know when coroutine has ended and in what state?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool fadeAutomatically = false;
    public float fadeTime;
    public CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
    public static bool isInState = false;
    private Coroutine _currentRoutine;
    private bool _currentDirection;
    private bool _nextDirection;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (canvasGroup == null)
        {
            canvasGroup = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Loading Saved Game Description").GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        }
    }

    public void StartFade(bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
    {
        if (_currentRoutine != null)
        {
            if (_currentDirection != isIn)
            {
                StopCoroutine(_currentRoutine);

                _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!fadeAutomatically)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
            {
                StartFade(false,false);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
            {
                StartFade(true,false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StartFade(_nextDirection,true);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Fade(CanvasGroup canvasGroup, bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
    {
        _currentDirection = isIn;

        var startValue = isIn ? 0 : 1;
        var targetValue = isIn ? 1 : 0;

        var elapsedTime = fadeTime * (isIn ? canvasGroup.alpha : (1 - canvasGroup.alpha));
        while (elapsedTime <= fadeTime)
        {
            canvasGroup.alpha = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, targetValue, elapsedTime / fadeTime);

            yield return null;

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        canvasGroup.alpha = targetValue;

        if (autoSwitch) _nextDirection = !isIn;

        _currentRoutine = null;

        if(isIn == false)
        {
            isInState = true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to know when the coroutine Fade has ended if isIn was true or false and then use it in this script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using TMPro;

public class SavingGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int resWidth = 1920;
    public int resHeight = 1080;
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public Fader fader;
    public TMP_InputField _inputField;

    private static int countName;

    private void Start()
    {
        countName = 0;
        
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + "Saved Screenshots",
            "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if(dirs.Length > 0)
        {
            countName = dirs.Length;
        }
    }

    public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/Saved Screenshots/SaveSlot{1} SavedGameSlot_{2}x{3}_{4}/SavedGameSlot_{1}x{2}_{3}.png",
            Application.persistentDataPath,
            countName,
            width, height, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
        {
            fader.StartFade(true, false);
        }

        if(Fader.isInState)
        {
            StartSaving();
            Fader.isInState = false;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        fader.StartFade(false, false);
    }

    public void StartSaving()
    {
        string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename);
        string descriptionContent = _inputField.text;
        if (_inputField.text.Length != 0)
        {
            string descriptionFileFolder = directory + "\\" + "Description.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(descriptionFileFolder, descriptionContent);
        }
        StartCoroutine(saveLoad.SaveWithTime(directory, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + ".savegame.txt"));

        countName++;
    }
}
```

I'm pressing the k key it's fading in then in the editor i'm pressing a ui button name Save and calling the method Save at this point i want to wait for the fade to finish fading out and only then to call StartSaving()

In the Update i did :

```
if(Fader.isInState)
            {
                StartSaving();
                Fader.isInState = false;
            }
```

but i messed all the flags in both scripts because now it's calling the StartSaving method before i pressed the ui Save button and called the Save method. so i mixed and messed the flags and the whole checking in the Update.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but ever since Unity 2017 you can use the `async/await` pattern in .NET 4.x rather than co-routines.  Apart from being able to  use _big boy toys_ such as being able to create a task safe in the knowledge it won't block Unity's primary UI thread; easy and automatic thread-marshalling; and state machines; determining if a `Task` has ended and in what state is child's play. ;)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade#taking-advantage-of-net-compatibility.  Meanwhile coroutines make re-entrancy easy!

Comment: Sound alike you need an enum rather than bool. Because if is running is false it triggers the save because it’s never been running. But is false. So you need a ready. Working. Done. And after saved. State gets changed to ready.

Comment: Another idea could be using DOTween or other tweening library. It's seems you got awful lots of code for a simple fade, why invent wheel again. DOTween's tweens has callbacks that will do their thing after tween is done as well as flags that indicates tween's end which seems to be what you need.